# Cluster analysis on time series samples

Tags: time-series, clustering, variance, generalized-linear-model, forecasting

In the follow-up to this [Ways to understand 2-dimensional time-series data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103989/ways-to-understand-2-dimensional-time-series-data)

I'm working on 2D time series data where two attributes are depth and temperature. When I plotted depth-vs-temp curve and saw its variation over time, the fluctuation occurs at few places only.

Lets say temperature is dependent on depth and it varies at few depths over time.

Would doing cluster analysis on each time sample and comparing it with the next one be good? The point is to statistically identify changes across timestamps. And then decide which are significant timestamp samples.

What models/papers should I study to get insights out of the data?

Comment: Any chance you could upload the plot? I'm not sure that I'm sure I know what you're describing. Also, what else do you know about the data? How was it collected, how many observations, etc.

Comment: Temperature samples are recorded for 1k depth samples. And this is recorded over 500 time samples, say 1-2 minutes apart. Depth samples are uniformaly distributed over a range. But, due to decimal corrections, over time samples depth values needn't be same. Makes it clear? Sorry for being cryptic.

Comment: That helps. I'd still like to see the plot, or some kind of mock-up if the data is confidential.

Comment: If you could tell me what inferences you would like to know. I'd prepare a mock-up based on that.

Comment: "when I plotted depth-vs-temp curve and saw its variation over time, the fluctuation occurs at few places only."

Comment: Yes. What I did was, I took depth-vs-temperature scatter plot for each time sample and looped it into a movie. When I saw it, mostly the line retains its basic form, pulsating 1% temperature changes. But at few couple of "bands of depths" places the temperature gradually increases with time, say increased by 10% by the end of the movie. Have I made it clear?

Comment: I think you should show the movie or plot, as it would convey what you're seeing without any misinterpretations.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, my immediate instinct is to fit a regression line at each time point, and then plot the coefficient(s) over time.

My next instinct is to compute a "distance" between each depth band using one of several distance functions. Then you can run cluster analysis on it directly, e.g. single-linkage cluster analysis. You could also apply multidimensional scaling, principal components analysis, or a network/graph representation and optionally run analyses on those.

There's an overview of the subject [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEAQFjAD&url=http://ai.ms.mff.cuni.cz/~sui/barton.pdf&ei=1rSmU6Nb0eGwBI_-gaAJ&usg=AFQjCNEspVcvO5nqsyDV_C80OLrxQsJpqQ&sig2=J9ewj8zvVef10HaHvXwS9Q) (pdf slides). Papers reviewing the subject [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320305001305) and [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0952197610001727).

Comment: I have just implemented both the ideas. Thanks. I'd try and further dive into pca and networks approach.